# Switch Apple ID

Tags: apple-id

I bought an iPad 2 last May and used my husband's Apple ID that he uses for iTunes.

I have used his ID to buy apps for my iPad 2 and even bought iTunes cards to put on his account. Well, now I have an iPhone, iMac and have my own Apple ID.

Question - can I switch it to my ID without him losing his ID?  I have found where I can edit my ID but I don't want him to lose his account.

Answer (score 5):

He won't lose his account if you switch Apple IDs. However, you might want to  continue to share his ID for iTunes and App Store purchases (for all of your Apple devices) so you will keep convenient access to the apps and media you've already purchased and you can both share your purchases on your various devices. You can use your new Apple ID for iCloud services.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one Apple ID linked to a device, and considering you now have the iPhone and a Mac it is a good idea to sign up for your own Apple ID rather than edit his.

In order to keep all your previous purchases you will need to sync the device with your computer.

However before you sync with the computer you should authorize both your new Apple ID and his old one. iTunes will then sync all the purchases made on both accounts to your devices, while keeping iCloud content linked to only your devices

Comment: You can have different Apple IDs, used for different purposes, on a single device. (I do this myself. See http://www.macworld.com/article/163013/2011/10/all_about_icloud_common_signup_scenarios.html for more info). Following Graeme's suggestion, you will have to log out of the "new" ID and enter the credentials for the old one any time you need to update or re-download apps purchased on the old account.  Sharing an Apple ID for iTunes/app purchases also makes it more convenient to share those purchases across the family unit.